# Как открыть существующий файл в VIM?

Tags: vim

Не знаю, может как для новичка в программировании VIM это слишком, но почему-то меня зацепила эта архаичная штуковина. Я прошел vimtutor и вроде чего-то понял о том, как использовать программу.

Но я второй день безуспешно ищу ответ на простейший вопрос, как открыть файл для редактирования из VIM?

Comment: А вообще, конечно, лучше использовать NerdTree - очень удобный плагин, практически незаменим, если нужно работать с многофайловым проектом.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как обычно, команда+аргумент:

```
vim filename.txt
```

Либо в самом редакторе

```
:e filename.txt
```

Comment: Я до этого видимо не дошел еще) Абсолютный путь нужно указывать?

Comment: Либо абсолютный, либо относительно каталога запуска.

Comment: `vim ../filename.txt`. `vim /home/user/filename.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно отрыть даже всю папку при старте или в запущенном vim

```
vim path_to_dir
:e .
```

Потом выбрать нужный файл

Отрыть можно сразу указав файл по абсолютному или относительному пути

```
vim path/to/file
vim ./filename
```

Есть must-have плагин - NerdTree который удобен своей простотой.
В англоязычной версии СО Vim/Emacs самые популярные редакторы текста в *nix ОС.

**Ссылки**

- https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree
- http://www.rayninfo.co.uk/vimtips.html

Answer (score 0):

```
:e <filename>  # Открыть файл

Вкладки 
:tabe <filename>  # Добавить вкладку с файлом
gt  # Cледующия вкладка
gT  # Предыдущая вкладка 

Окна
:sp <filename>  # Открыть файл в горизонтальном сплит-окне. Ctrl-w + n
:vsp <filename>  # Открыть файл в вертикальном сплит-окне
Ctrl-w и W  # Переключение между окнами
```